# How to read picture from RSS Feed and show in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, rss

I try to learn RSS Feed from this [tutorial](http://amitandroid.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-rssfeed-with-async-task-example.html). After read that tutorial I download source and test RSS Feed. but it can't read picture from RSS to show in android because my RSS have no tag *media:content* but it use tag *enclosure* such as

```
<enclosure url="http://p3.s1sf.com/ns/0/ud/238/1192436/1.jpg" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

when I run the code from tutorial it show like this in log.

> 06-19 08:43:57.637: D/rssfeed(785):
>   imageAndTexts1.get(position).getImgLink() :: null ::

So I checked **XmlHandler.java** in startElement function.

```
if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("media:content"))

        {
            if (!atts.getValue("url").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                feedStr.setImgLink(atts.getValue("url").toString());
            } else {
                feedStr.setImgLink("");
            }
        }
```

I replace with

```
if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure"))

        {
            if (!atts.getValue("url").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                feedStr.setImgLink(atts.getValue("url").toString());
            } else {
                feedStr.setImgLink("");
            }
        }
```

but It show error like this

```
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at com.amit.adapter.RssReaderListAdapter.getView(RssReaderListAdapter.java:64)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-19 08:08:09.165: E/AndroidRuntime(2661):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know how to read image from RSS both tag media:content and enclosure. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

U get an url through rss feed and pass the url to this function like this
`

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

        final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        copy(in, out);
        out.flush();

        final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //options.inSampleSize = 1;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
    } finally {
        closeStream(in);
        closeStream(out);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

`
and finally u get an image then u set it into the imageview like this  Imageview.setImageBitmap

Comment: I can't get URL it show like this  imageAndTexts1.get(position).getImgLink() :: null ::

Comment: use this ' if (atts.getValue("url").toString()!=null) {
         
        String url=atts.getValue("url").toString();
            feedStr.setImgLink(url);
        }' use break point over here and check what string in url

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error relavent how you parse rss. Error is "NetworkOnMainThreadException" so this means you are trying to get this rss on main thread, Android platform is not allowed to access network on main thread to prevent locking user's events. You must call this rss reading method on a background thread...

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ReadRss();
        } 
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use this downloading action on the main thread with using `AsyncTask`. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).